# Opencart2 restrict user group to change stock in edit product page

Tags: opencart2.x

Is it possible to disallow access to quantity fields in opencart 2 admin product edit (general quantity and option values quantity)?
I want only the admin to be able to change the quantities.

Can i use something like if user_group_id!=1 (not admin) echo "readonly" to the input field of quantity?

I've tried for test to add a readonly, without if , to the input field in admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl but nothing changed to the code as seen in view source.

Which file can i edit ?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. I think this will help you

> 1. admin/controller/catelog/product.php

Add following code before : `if (!isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {`

```
// load user group model
$this->load->model('user/user');
$user_details = $this->model_user_user->getUser($this->session->data['user_id']);
$data['user_group_id'] = $user_details['user_group_id'];
```

> 2. admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl

replace quantity html to following code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-quantity"><?php echo $entry_quantity; ?></label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <?php if(isset($user_group_id) && $user_group_id == 1) { ?>
              <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_quantity; ?>" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
           <?php } else { 
               echo $quantity;
            } ?>
        </div>
 </div>
```

**Note : This is based on admin user group.**

Comment: Nothing happens when i edit admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl, even when i empty this file and hit refresh tha page still shows. 
Is it possible for opencart to cache this tpl? I dont use the default theme, but does it have to do something with the admin pages? If it helps i use journal theme with oc 2.0.2.0. Thank you.